# Android java and xml error

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having problems with my android code.  Could i get some help?  My java is as follows:

```
package ryan.helloworld;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class mainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HWbutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
}
```

I'm getting an error with my button.setOnClickListener

My XML is as follows

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".mainActivity" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Its saying menu items should specify a name.  Any help here?

Comment: you have to override the `onClick()` method in your `onClickListener` anonymous class.

Comment: put `final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HWbutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` this inside `onCreate()` and try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two issues are unreleated. Other people have solved the Java issue, so I'll give you the XML help.

Menu items must have both an ID and a title. The ID is used to refer to the menu item, and the title is what is displayed to the user.

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for help now I just need to destroy the button and output hello world! I don't know a lot of the code cause I was doing applets before this and don't know XML.

Answer (score 0):

include the button definition & onClickListener within the onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HWbutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
             ...
             }
    }
}
```

is that xml your activity xml? if so, you need to include the button tag with its attribute. you are already referring to `HWbutton` ?

Comment: ok i understand but how to i make it output hello world! and make the button dissaper?

Comment: Actually the eroor was pointed out by me..see my comment... @TheJavaCoder

Comment: Ya i looked at your comment and ranguebanelings